# Python create a module from string and run the module

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to create a module and run it all from a string but I get an exception:

```
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 568, in module_from_spec
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'loader'
```

My attempt:

```
from importlib.util import module_from_spec

task_string = """
print ('Hello world!')        
        """
module = module_from_spec("module_name")
exec(task_string, module.__dict__)
```

I know that I can use `eval(task_string)` but I wanted to run `task_string` in a sandbox, in other words, it would not access other variables in this scope. Thank you.

Comment: If restricting access to the current scope's variables is your only reason for using the module approach, it's worth noting that you can do that with the two optional arguments to `exec`.

Comment: @jedwards can you please provide an example? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Re: discussion in comments:

Consider this example:

```
var = "123"

code = "print(var)"

exec(code)
```

Calling `exec` like this will execute the string in the current scope, so it'll have access to your `var` and will print "123".

But you can restrict eval's context by specifying dictionaries that should be used as the globals and locals respectively:

```
var = "123"

code = "print(var)"

sandbox_globals = {}    
sandbox_locals = {}

exec(code, sandbox_globals, sandbox_locals)
```

Here, an exception will be raised:

```
NameError: name 'var' is not defined
```

Because you've specified the globals and locals to be used.

You can explicitly allow `exec` access by something like:

```
sandbox_globals = {'var':var}
```

**But**, you haven't *fully* restricted the sandbox this way.

```
sandbox_locals = {}
sandbox_globals = {}

code = "print(2**8)"

exec(code, sandbox_globals, sandbox_locals)
```

This code will work without throwing, printing 256.  `print` works, and comes from somewhere.  This is because `__builtins__` is automatically added to `sandbox_globals` if you don't explicitly prevent that:

```
sandbox_locals = {}
sandbox_globals = {}

code = "print(2**8)"

sandbox_globals['__builtins__'] = {}

exec(code, sandbox_globals, sandbox_locals)
```

This will raise an Exception, since you're no longer providing `print`:

```
NameError: name 'print' is not defined
```